# Wants to collect browser console data for failed test cases in pytest framework

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I am using python selenium pytest to automate a web application. In this, I want to download the browser console data for the failed test cases not for passed test case for debugging purpose and the console log in file.

My conftest.py is

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup(request, browser):

    # driver setup done here

    yield driver

    log.info("Closing browser")
    driver.close()
    log.info("Quitting browser")
    driver.quit()
```

I modified my conftest.py file as below

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup(request, browser):

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
    options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
    options.set_capability("acceptInsecureCerts", True)

    preferences = {"profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
                  "download.default_directory": r""+Constants.path+"",
                  "directory_upgrade": True}
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)
    capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
    capabilities["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"browser": "ALL"}
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_autoinstaller.install(), 
                               options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)

    yield driver

    # Below is the code used to collect the browser console log and save into browser_console.log

    log_path = "../Logs/browser_console.log"
    class_name = request.cls.__name__
    with open(log_path, "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(f"\n\n{'=' * 20} {class_name} {'=' * 20}\n")
        for entry in driver.get_log("browser"):
            f.write(f"[{entry['level']}] {entry['message']}\n")

    log.info("Closing browser")
    driver.close()
    log.info("Quitting browser")
    driver.quit()
```

But this code runs for each test case wether it is passed or failed. I just wants to run it only for failed test cases to collect data for debugging.

Comment: Note that f.write(f"...) is not indented, like the rest of the code...

Comment: You can try to put a try after the setup definition, and except block with log information

Comment: Updated the post, In actual code it is indented. Thanks @Magaren

Comment: `try...except` block won't work here because a False assert is not considered an exception or error.